# Excel VBA When using SaveAs Filename, strange things are happening to the file extension?

Tags: vba, excel

This is the line in my code:
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=curPath & cell.Value & Format(Now, "dmmmyyyy" & ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

Here's the extension from a couple of the files:
.xl47x
.xl35x

I tried using ".xlsm" and I got:
.xl78
.xl22

I can force change the name and then the file will open - but why is it changing the extension? Does someone know what is going on? I've never seen this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file extension in the code needs to be outside the Format function.  See the suggested approach below.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=curPath & cell.Value & Format(Now, "dmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I believe this response solves the issue you are having.  If so, please credit with a check mark.  If not, let me know what issues you have and I will attempt to address them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, that was a miss on my part.